# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

json encoded string is

```
{
    "user": [{
        "id": "45",
        "name": "Raj",
        "loc": "kizhakood",
        "dist": "wayanad",
        "phone": "9815678421",
        "email": "rajsahanca@gmail.c",
        "gender": "male",
        "proofid": "2",
        "sslc": "SSLC",
        "plus2": "PLUS 2",
        "degree": "DEGREE",
        "pg": ""
    }]
}
```

when I try to JSON.parse(responcetext)

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data

javascript

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        function loadup(str){

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var jsontext = xmlhttp.responseText;

        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=jsontext;

        var userobj=JSON.parse(jsontext);
        document.getElementById("myd").innerHTML=userobj.user[0].name;

    }
        } 

        xmlhttp.open("GET","plain.php?edit="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>`
```

php file contains

```
<?php
   include"connection.php";
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
     $json_res=array();
    $json_res = array('user'=>array($row));





    echo json_encode($json_res);


    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you add complete code of how you're getting this JSON

Comment: It's valid JSON, and it works for me in Chrome and IE.

Comment: why are you `parsing` it

Comment: @DanielB: I think he is getting already response in Json format and trying to parse it again.

Comment: @ozil — Because you have to parse JSON to turn it into a useful data structure.

Comment: Given a variable `responcetext` containing that JSON, you [won't get the error](http://jsbin.com/sapofikera/1/edit?js,output). You don't even have a character at line 1 column 4 (or 3, or 2). You need to provide a more complete test case to demonstrate the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Quentin it is already in `useful data structure` ...

Comment: @ozil — There's nothing in the question which demonstrates that.

Comment: @Quentin it is a valid JSON object.

Comment: @VivekGupta — The JSON given in the question is a valid JSON text. The error message shows that `responcetext` is not a string containing that JSON. That the error message complains about column 4 (and not 2) suggests `responcetext` isn't that JSON parsed into a JavaScript object either.

Comment: @DanielB  please check my javascript and php

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=jsontext;` to `document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(document.createTextNode(jsontext))` to make sure that you don't have any HTML prefixing your JSON.

Comment: changed but stil n error!!

Comment: @Quentin - how to convert a json encode data to string ???

Comment: @Quentin-  finally i found it !!! the problem is my json data not a string ,...

thats y i cant JSON.parse (responcetext)
i need to convert that responce text to string .. how can i convert it???

Comment: @RajMohan — That doesn't make sense. `xmlhttp.responseText` can't be anything other than a string. If it isn't a string, what is it?

Comment: The point of changing `innerHTML` to `createTextNode` was to help you see exactly what the data is to make it easier to debug. It wasn't supposed to fix the problem by itself.

Answer (score -1):

You already have valid json,  you can access attributes like below

```
var json = '{"user":[{"id":"45","name":"Raj","loc":"kizhakood","dist":"wayanad","phone":"9815678421","email":"rajsahanca@gmail.c","gender":"male","proofid":"2","sslc":"SSLC","plus2":"PLUS 2","degree":"DEGREE","pg":""}]}';

var json1 = JSON.parse(json)

alert(json1.user[0].id);
alert(json1.user[0].name);
alert(json1.user[0].email);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. If it was parsed into a JavaScript object then you'd expect the error at column 2 not 4.

Comment: @Quentin Why you need to parse, if you can access it like I mentioned in my answer

Comment: You are confusing JSON and JavaScript object literals. If it is JSON then it needs to be parsed. If it is a JavaScript object literal, then the error message received trying to parse it as JSON is not the one I'd expect.

Comment: @Quentin -please check my javascript and php